# binding two VerticalScrollBars one to another

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

I have two TextBoxes in the control , and I have in both of thems two VerticalScrollBar.
I want to bind the VerticalScrollBars between them , if one goes up the secound will go also etc...
Is it possible if so how i can do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a real binding but it works:

```xml
<TextBox Name="scrlTB1" Height="100" ScrollBar.Scroll="Scroll" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
<TextBox Name="scrlTB2" Height="100" ScrollBar.Scroll="Scroll" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
```

```
private void Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender == scrlTB1)
    {
        scrlTB2.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue);
    }
    else
    {
        scrlTB1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

(*This example ignores the possibility of horizontal scrolling*)

Comment: Worked with a minor adjustment: I had to change ScrollEventArgs ->

System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e

Comment: works better for all cases  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151974/synchronized-scrolling-of-two-scrollviewers-whenever-any-one-is-scrolled-in-wpf