# Multi column listview UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I need to do this layout in my windows app (min 2 columns)

[image]

I've tried sync scroll in two ListView but it very laging. 
The most important, I need high performance with virtualization.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't think this is a `ListView` control in your picture at all, do you need a synchronized listview or a waterfall layout? with a waterfall layout, the data virtualization may lost.

Comment: I guess you can use VariableSizedWrapGrid  here. refer this link  https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/variable-sized-items-with-gridview-control-for-windows-store-apps/

Comment: Yes, i need something like this:
https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout
but I haven't found anything for Windows...

VariableSizedWrapGrid doesn't use Virtualization and therefore doesn't solve my problem

Comment: I've solved my problem ;) 
I've used scrollviewer with my own virtualization 
https://github.com/sayler8182/VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid

Answer (score 2):

With the lastest release the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/store/p/uwp-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq?rtc=1) provides such a control.
It's called `StaggeredPanel`.

An example can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/StaggeredPanel).

Here is an example screenshot taken from the the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/store/p/uwp-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq?rtc=1):
[image: Here is an example from screenshoot taken from the the UWP Community Toolkit]

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure about your requirement. But you may look into this solution [Synchronized scrolling of two ScrollViewers whenever any one is scrolled in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151974/synchronized-scrolling-of-two-scrollviewers-whenever-any-one-is-scrolled-in-wpf)