# Synchronized scrolling of two ScrollViewers with different content sizes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I have something like this:

[Synchronized scrolling of two ScrollViewers whenever any one is scrolled in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151974/synchronized-scrolling-of-two-scrollviewers-whenever-any-one-is-scrolled-in-wpf)

The problem is that the size of the content of the Scrollviewer do not have the same width.

I have managed to calculate the proportional movement of the bars but does not take into account the size of the bars, which are different from each other:

```
sv2.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.HorizontalOffset * (sv1.Width / grid1.Width) / (sv2.Width / grid2.Width));

sv1.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.HorizontalOffset * (sv2.Width / grid2.Width) / (sv1.Width / grid1.Width));
```

[image]

It only coordinates the start of the bars, regardless of their size. Any ideas?

Comment: And what result exactly you expect? Synchronize the ends of the bars? But then you won't like that start of bars are not syncrhonized. Maybe synchronize the centers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate the scrolling position in a fraction of the total:

After scrolloffset on sv1 changes try something like

```
var scFract = sv1.HorizontalOffset / sv1.ScrollableWith;
sv2.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(sv2.ScrollableWith * scFract);
```