# WPF "overlapping" scroll viewer

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, scrollbar

I have a WPF Grid with 3 "sections": 1, 2, and 3.

When Horizontal (H) is moved, I need 1 and 3 to move.

When Vertical (V) is moved, I need 2 and 3 to move.

Is this possible with such a layout to use a ScrollViewer, or am I looking for a more complex solution?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer found after some messing around.

- wrap 1, 2, 3 in ScrollView controls
- set (3) H and V ScrollBars to "Auto"
- set (1) and (2) ScrollBars to "Hidden"
- subscribe to (3) "ScrollChanged" event
- set (2) ScrollToVerticalOffset() with (3).VerticalOffset
- set (1) ScrollToHorizontalOffset() with (3).HorizontalOffset

Thanks 
[Synchronized scrolling of two ScrollViewers whenever any one is scrolled in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151974/synchronized-scrolling-of-two-scrollviewers-whenever-any-one-is-scrolled-in-wpf)