# WPF: DataGrid delegated scrolling

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have `DataGrid` and other elements contained within the `ScrollViewer` and want to find out how it is possible to delegate `DataGrid` scrolling on the outer `ScrollViewer`. I mean if the mouse pointer is not on the `DataGrid` - scrolling is executed on the containing `ScrollViewer`, but once the mouse pointer is on the `DataGrid` - it will scroll instead of "main" `ScrollViewer`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Content1/>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"/>

        <Content2 Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Is there any way to merge scrolling between the outer `ScrollViewer` and contained `DataGrid`?

Comment: I guess I need to disable `DataGrid` scrolling to make it scrollable for the outer `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151974/synchronized-scrolling-of-two-scrollviewers-whenever-any-one-is-scrolled-in-wpf

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg, thanks for the info, but it seems the question title was a bit confusing. I changed it to describe my goal more accurately.